# „User Experience“ vs. „User-Experience“

Tags: spelling, hyphen

Es geht um den **Bindestrich** bei *User-Experience*. Im Englischen wird klarerweise keiner geschrieben. Ich schreibe meine Abschlussarbeit zum Thema Usability, und da kommen eben auch *User Experience* und viele weitere ähnliche Begriffe vor. Gibt es hier eine allgemeine Regel, die man anwenden kann für Beispiele wie *Usability Evaluation, User Experience, Usability Testing, Mobile Usability, Usability Engineering*, usw.?

Auf [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Experience) wird keiner verwendet, aber das würde ich jetzt nicht als glaubwürdigste Quelle bezeichnen.

Comment: Ich würde die Begriffe, die imho größtenteils keine etablierten Lehnwörter im Deutschen sind, in der Originalschreibweise belassen, eventuell sogar in Anführungszeichen oder per Zeichensatzstil (fett oder kursiv) hervorgehoben.

Answer (score 6):

Ja, diese allgemeine Regel gibt es, oder vielleicht besser gesagt ein Zusammenwirken mehrerer Regeln. Eine zusammenfassende Erklärung findest Du z.B. beim [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Fremdwortern-aus-dem-Englischen) und bei [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Bindestrich/Fremdwort.html).

Um die Regeln anzuwenden, musst Du die Wortarten bestimmen, aus denen die Zusammensetzung besteht. (Kenntnisse einer fremden Grammatik als Voraussetzung, um korrektes Deutsch schreiben zu können - willkommen bei der Rechtschreibreform...) Bei *user experience* handelt es sich um eine Verbindung zwischen zwei Substantiven. Diese sind Gegenstand von [§37 E3](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GetrZusammen/pgf37-38.html#pgf37-E3) und [§45 E1](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Bindestrich/pgf40-45.html#pgf45-E1) der amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln.

> **§37** E3
>   Dieser Regel folgen auch lexikalisierte, ursprünglich aus dem Englischen stammende bzw. aus englischen Einheiten gebildete Zusammensetzungen:
>   *Bandleader, Cheerleader, Chewinggum, Mountainbike, Bluejeans, Hardware, Swimmingpool.*
>
> **45** E1
>   Aus anderen Sprachen stammende Verbindungen aus Substantiv + Substantiv, die sich im Deutschen grammatisch wie Zusammensetzungen verhalten, werden zusammengeschrieben; ebenso ist die verdeutlichende Schreibung mit Bindestrich möglich.
>   *Sexappeal (Sex-Appeal), Sciencefiction (Science-Fiction), Shoppingcenter(Shopping-Center), Desktoppublishing (Desktop-Publishing), Midlifecrisis(Midlife-Crisis)*

Während man bei §37 E3 noch diskutieren kann, wie "lexikalisch" hier wohl gemeint ist (aber mit dem m.E. ziemlich seltenen *Chewinggum* als Beispiel kann es eigentlich nicht sehr streng sein), ist §45 E1 für unseren Fall hier sehr klar: *user experience* verhält sich im Deutschen wie ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv, folglich schreibt man *User-Experience* oder theoretisch auch *Userexperience*.

Comment: Das gilt übrigens (nach AR § 37 E3) nur für „**lexikalisierte**, ursprünglich aus dem Englischen stammende bzw. aus englischen Einheiten gebildete Zusammensetzungen“; ob _user experience_ tatsächlich in den deutschen Wortschatz eingegangen ist, ist fraglich.

Comment: @chirlu Wie das zu verstehen ist, wäre mal eine eigene Frage wert. Unter dem Duden-Link sind _Braintrust_ und _Hangover_ als Beispiele aufgeführt. Es würde mir nicht einfallen, diese als lexikalisiert zu bezeichnen.

Comment: Könnte ein Duden-Problem sein. Die Beispiele in der Amtlichen Regelung waren passender, soweit ich mich erinnere (kann gerade nicht nachschauen).

Comment: Ich frage mich auch gerade, wie _Hangover_ da hineinpaßt. Seit wann ist _over_ ein Substantiv?

Comment: @chirlu Ist es nicht, genausowenig wie _blue_ in _Bluejeans_. §37 beginnt mit dem Satz: "Substantive, Adjektive, Verbstämme, Pronomen oder Partikeln können mit Substantiven Zusammensetzungen bilden." - Ich hab die Antwort nochmal erweitert. Ist es jetzt klarer?